# Registry is not accessible in Windows 8 (32/64 bit) while active directory deployment

Tags: visual-c++, active-directory, windows-8, registry, driver

This is problem with deleting a printer driver in windows 8 pc.

Our applicaton is working fine in UI Level deployment, we have installed and uninstalled successfully.

we have tested our Application in Windows 8 (32 and 64 bit) from UI Level and as well as PUSH Deployments.

But in PUSH (Active Directory deployment), "OpenPrinter()" function is failed to get the handle of requested printer driver. Then the deleteprinter also failed.

We have verified that the function is getting perameters as we expected. But it is failed.

Since the issue is happening only in Windows 8.

Servers are Windows 2003 and Windows 2008 r2 and Deploying per mechine basis.

Application developed in VC++ (VS 2008) and packaged with InstallShield12.

In our investigation we have found that Registry is not accessible to 'Openprinter()' function and it is failed to return the handle.

While we install the applicaton from PUSH, it is installing with SYSTEM account. We have verified this.

Is there any limitations to use the registry in Windows 8 PC?
or do we need to fix/set/configure any settings in Windows 8 PC?
or Is there any forbidden to access the registry for SYSTEM account?

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two potential reasons: 1) RPC is disabled by default; and 2) UAC is preventing Win8 from accepting API-type requests. The answer to problem #1 is to either change policy to allow RPC or use WMI. The answer to problem #2 is to either disable UAC (not recommended) or sign the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Registry is not accessible in Windows 8 (32/64 bit) while active directory deployment***
Finally things are broken out..
The main reason is openprinter API depends on registry to get the handle for requested printer.
By the time we have called the API, the registry is not available for it.
 when we have waited to complete 2 minutes, the API returns the handle.
hence my PUSH uninstall is completed with out hang. Now problem is solved in my case.
But it is a limitation with Windows 8.